# Вывод данных из mssql_query

Tags: php, sql-server

Есть запрос к функции на mssql сервере

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM function_name(value)';
$result = mssql_query($query) or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());
```

Для начала пытаюсь просто вывести данные на экран

```
$Row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $Row['row1'].' | '.$Row['row2'].' | '.$Row['row3'].' | '.$Row['row4'];
```

В mssql функции `row1` объявлен как `datetime`, `row2` как `int`. Эти поля выводятся без проблем.

Но вот `row3` и `row4` объявлены как `numeric` и при выводе этих полей, я не получаю ничего.
Проверил, что же мне приходит в `$result`

```
echo '\'' . mssql_field_name($result, 2) . '\' типа ' .mssql_field_type($result, 2) . 
 '(' . mssql_field_length($result, 2) . ')<br>';
```

Выводит `row3` типа `REAL(8)`.
На сервере используется php5.2.6.1-1.

Comment: `var_dump($Row)` ?

Comment: row3=>null, row4=>null

Comment: попробуйте в запросе привести к `float`

Comment: Попробовал cast и convert. Не помогло. В mssql management studio все отрабатывает корректно.

Comment: если после `cast(row4 as float) as row4` данные не возвращаются, то это как минимум странно. уж обычный вещественный тип должен возвращаться без проблем.

Comment: Да это максимально странно... И что с этим делать пока без понятия. Это может быть проблема в mssql функции ???

Comment: @Dmitry если в SSMS все отображается корректно - то дело не в ней (функции). Логи php сервера смотрели? Может есть сообщения о каких-либо ошибках/проблемах.